# Jest - No output of test results

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs, yarnpkg

I've been having difficulties with Jest ever since I tried to begin using it. No tests I try to run and with what options I try to pass Jest, I never get the 'Pass' / 'Fail' output results in the console.

Jest always just outputs 'Done'

Using the 'Nuxt CLI' there is a default test written as:

```
import { mount } from '@vue/test-utils'
import Logo from '@/components/Logo.vue'

describe('Logo', () => {
  test('is a Vue instance', () => {
    const wrapper = mount(Logo)
    expect(wrapper.isVueInstance()).toBeTruthy()
  })
})
```

So far I have tried:

```
yarn test
yarn test --verbose
yarn test --watch
yarn test --watchAll
yarn test --no-watchmen
```

Every single time, the result is as follows:

```
yarn run v1.21.1
$ jest
Done in 0.72s.
```

Current **jest.config.js**:

```
module.exports = {
  moduleNameMapper: {
    '^@/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/$1',
    '^~/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/$1',
    '^vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.common.js'
  },
  moduleFileExtensions: ['js', 'vue', 'json'],
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.js$': 'babel-jest',
    '.*\\.(vue)$': 'vue-jest'
  },
  collectCoverage: true,
  collectCoverageFrom: [
    '<rootDir>/components/**/*.vue',
    '<rootDir>/pages/**/*.vue'
  ]
}
```

This seems to be the default config for Nuxt.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I figured it out (kind-of).

My tests run fine with the following:

```
yarn test --no-watchman
```

I can't figure out why watchman is causing me so many issues but this does seem to help.

**More Info:**
https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/2219

Answer (score 0):

Jest looks for files ending with `.spec.js` or `.test.js` file formats. Try putting your test in a file ending with `.spec.js` or `.test.js` file. Also you can configure `jest`, using `jest.config.js` file.

One such example of using `jest.config.js` file is

```
const path = require('path')

module.exports = {
    rootDir: path.resolve(__dirname),
    moduleFileExtensions: [
        'js',
        'json',
        'vue',
        'ts'
    ],
    moduleNameMapper: {
        '^@/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/src/$1'
    },
    transform: {
        ".*\\.(vue)$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/vue-jest",
        "^.+\\.(js|jsx)?$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/babel-jest",
        "^.+\\.ts$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/ts-jest"
    },
    testRegex: "(/__tests__/.*|(\\.|/)(test|spec))\\.(jsx?|tsx?)$",
    snapshotSerializers: [
        "jest-serializer-vue"
    ],
    testEnvironment: "jsdom",
    setupFiles: [
        "<rootDir>/globals.js"
    ]
}
```

Comment: Hey madhu, I have a 'test' folder with a 'Logo.spec.js' file within it. This is directly from the Nuxt CLI so I assume it will be correct as theres nothing in the Nuxt GitHub issues regarding Jest.

Comment: can you try with putting the file at the root level itself, instead of under `test` folder and see if jest picks it up

Comment: Hey, moving the test to the top level folder gave the same results... Done in 0.75s.

Comment: By `nuxt` u mean `create-nuxt-app`?

Comment: Yes, I've also tried creating an empty folder and adding jest, then writing the 'Sum' example here: https://jestjs.io/docs/en/getting-started.html - This too results in just the 'Done in 0.69s.' I seriously cannot figure out why I'm not getting the results. Also tried with both Yarn and Npm

Comment: try changing the file to `Logo.test.js`

Comment: Unfortunately that too makes no difference. I just get 'Done 0.69s.'

Comment: Annoyingly, when I do what I'm doing in VsCode on Code Sandbox, the tests run fine. I have no idea what I'm doing wrong on my local project!!!!!